# How to edit and update data in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I have a form that a user keys in and submits successfully. I want a user to be able to edit that form by clicking on an edit icon and edit the user data, I have managed to pull data from the api, but when I try to assign the access the values they are all null I end up with an undefined error what Am I doing wrong?

What I have done so far

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
        this._activatedroute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
          this.id = params.get('id');
        });
        let user = this.service.getUserSession();
        if (user != null) {
          this.project = user.currentProject.id;
        }
        this.userSession = this.userSessionService.getSession("usersession");
        this.projectId = this.userSession.currentProject.id;
        this.totalTeamsData = await this.teamService.getTeamList(this.projectId);
        await this.getTicketData();
      }
    
      async getTicketData(): Promise<void> {
          this.ticketData = await this.ticketService.getTicket(this.id, this.projectId);
          await this.toggleTicketDetails();
        
      }
    
      toggleTicketDetails() {
        console.log("the dats is", this.ticketData); //this shows the data from the api with all the fields
console.log("the dats is", this.ticketData.title); //this shows undefined 

        this.title = this.ticketData.title;
        this.description = this.ticketData.description;
        this.teamId = this.ticketData.teamId;
        this.totalTeamsData.forEach(async (data: string) => {
          if (data === this.teamId) {
            this.totalTeamMembersData = await this.teamService.getTeamMembers(this.projectId, this.teamId);
            this.totalEAData = await this.teamService.getTeamEAList(this.projectId, this.teamId);
          }
        });
        this.assignedTo = this.ticketData.assignedTo;
        this.eaId = this.ticketData.eaId;
        this.countryId = this.ticketData.countryId;
        this.projectId = this.ticketData.projectID;
        this.country = this.ticketData.country;
        this.priority = this.ticketData.priority;
        this.category = this.ticketData.category;
        this.status = this.ticketData.status;
        this.lab = this.ticketData.lab;
        this.impact = this.ticketData.impact;
        this.content = this.ticketData.content;
        this.resolution = this.ticketData.resolution;
      }
```

when I Console log `console.log("the dats is", this.ticketData);` the json is there as

```
{
  "id": "4e600c3d-efed-43c2-b395-6238510dda24",
  "title": "Test",
  "assignedTo": "tester@gmail.com",
  "description": "Test",
  "resolution": null,
  "country": "USA",
  "projectID": "ABC",
  "teamId": "901",
  "eaId": "901",
  "countryId": "0001",
  "priority": "Urgent",
  "status": "Open",
  "lab": null,
  "category": "Duplicate",
  "content": null,
  "impact": null,
  "dateCreated": 1619313188806,
  "createdBy": "tester@gmail.com"
}
```

why is this giving me undefined `this.title = this.ticketData.title;` and all others ?

This is some bit of the html

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title" style="color: black;">Title<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="color: black;"
                                    required id="title" name="title" [(ngModel)]="title">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description" style="color: black;">Description<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="3" style="color: black;"
                                    required id="description" name="description" [(ngModel)]="description">
                                </textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

What am I wrong, have tried to study the angualr google docs no luck from my , I would appreciate anyhelp

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: It's not clear exactly what's happening but you have a serious race condition that will cause bugs. `toggleTicketDetails` is very problematic. It isn't asynchronous and uses `xs.forEach(async x => ...)`. Use `await Promise.all(xs.map(async x => ...))` instead and make `toggleTicketDetails` `async`

Comment: Hi @AluanHaddad fixes that race condition, but still can see the submitted data on the forms

Comment: can u try make a minimal reproduce?